# Typescript type annotations for generics with constraints

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a curried function with generics that I don’t know how to use without losing precise type information. I am able to use it by specifying a concrete type, but then I cannot use it in another context. I am able to use it with a minimal type, but then typescript loses information about the function output.

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
const filterBy = <T>(check: (x: T) => boolean) => (arr: T[]): T[] => {
  return arr.filter(check)
}

interface SpecializedTypeWithIdAndMore {
  id: string
  anotherField: string
}

const items: SpecializedTypeWithIdAndMore[] = [
  /* ... */
]

// This is working but can only be applied to SpecializedTypeWithIdAndMore
const grouperSpecialized = filterBy<SpecializedTypeWithIdAndMore>(
  x => x.id === 'something',
)
const groupedItemsSpecialized = grouperSpecialized(items)
// groupedItemsSpecialized is SpecializedTypeWithIdAndMore[]

// This is working, but information about the input type is lost
const grouperTypeLost = filterBy<{ id: string }>(x => x.id === 'something')
const groupedItemsTypeLost = grouperTypeLost(items)
// groupedItemsTypeLost is { id: string }[]

// I would like to write something like this, but it does not work
const grouperWanted = filterBy<T extends { id: string }>(x => x.id === 'something')
const groupedItemsWanted = grouperWanted(items)
// I would like groupedItemsWanted to be SpecializedTypeWithIdAndMore[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work `const grouperWanted: <T extends { id: string }>(arr: T[]) => T[] = filterBy(x => x.id === 'something')`